# How to Run multiple commands in node at once

Tags: javascript, node.js

so im here trying to run multiple commands in node.js at once , is there any possibilty i can do that ? or maybe if i can run them at the same time , is there any way i can make a file including each command i want to run and it will do them one by one ? for example i wanna do like this

```
 node src\samples\search_listing1.js
 node src\samples\search_listing2.js
 node src\samples\search_listing3.js
 node src\samples\search_listing4.js
 node src\samples\search_listing5.js
 node src\samples\search_listing6.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use chaining - just make each command an NPM command:

```
npm search1 && npm search2 && npm search3...
```

It's also better to use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) for this:

```
concurrently "npm search1 && npm search2 && npm search3"
```

Comment: i tried the concurrently command.. but it just run first command then gives me this error 

[0] node src\samples\rl_listing.js && node src\samples\rl_listing2.js && node src\samples\rl_listing3.js exited with code 1

Comment: Nevermind , the problem was with my file.. thank you for the help apperciated !

Comment: doesn't that second example just run the same things one after the other anyway? that's what `&&` does in linux

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure both of these examples run the commands sequentially :/

Concurrently runs each argument in parallel, but there is only one argument in this example. I thought it would be something like
`concurrently "npm search1" "npm search2" "npm search3"`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the by the file separator you are running on windows.

You could use the following script to start them all concurrently and write their output into their own individual files

```
(
    start "search_listing1" cmd /C "node src\samples\search_listing1.js 2&>1 > search_listing1.out"
    start "search_listing2" cmd /C "node src\samples\search_listing2.js 2&>1 > search_listing2.out"
    start "search_listing3" cmd /C "node src\samples\search_listing3.js 2&>1 > search_listing3.out"
    start "search_listing4" cmd /C "node src\samples\search_listing4.js 2&>1 > search_listing4.out"
    start "search_listing5" cmd /C "node src\samples\search_listing5.js 2&>1 > search_listing5.out"
    start "search_listing6" cmd /C "node src\samples\search_listing6.js 2&>1 > search_listing6.out"
) | pause
```